# Emit events outside the connection scope in a promise

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, q, asyncsocket

I'm working on a matchmaking web app and I use **ExpressJs**, **Redis** and **Socket.io**.

The story :

1. I submit a form (in AJAX) with your username, the mission name
   and the difficulty
2. I loop through all teams related with the selected mission and I
   determine which one is available
3. And then I want to add the current "client" to a channel (the
   selected team) and I want to broadcast a message to all users of the
   channel like :

```js
client.join(team);
io.in(team).emit('matchmakingInProgress', teamData);
```

The fact is I use Promise in order to avoid a big callbacks Hell and I don't have access to these variables io and socket because they are used previsouly, I'm looking for a way for retrieving them.

*app.js*

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('./events/sockets').listen(server),
    port = process.env.PORT || 8080
;

// other stuff here ...

app.use(require('./controllers'));

server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port ' + port)
});
```

*events/sockets.js*

```
var socketio = require('socket.io');

module.exports.listen = function(app) {
    io = socketio(app);

    io.on('connection', function(client) {
        console.log('Client connected...');

        client.on('join', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            var clientsCount = io.sockets.sockets.length;

            client.broadcast.emit('clientsCount', clientsCount);
            client.emit('clientsCount', clientsCount);
        });

         client.on('disconnect', function() {
            console.log('Client disconnected...');

            client.broadcast.emit('clientsCount', clientsCount);
        });
    });

    return io;
}
```

*controllers/matchmaking.js*

```js
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router()
;

router.post('/:name/:difficulty', function(req, res) {

    // Others functions

    function dispatchTeamCompletionInProgress(teamData) {
        io.join(teamData.name);
        client.in(teamData.name).emit('matchmakingInProgress', teamData.length);
    }

    matchmakingService
        .getTeamsRelatedToAskedMission()
        .then(getTeamsLength)
        .then(getAvailableTeam)
        .then(addPlayer);
        .then(dispatchTeamCompletionInProgress); // <--- At this moment I want to emit a message
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: It isn't really clear to me exactly what your question is.  Are you just trying to figure out how to get the `io` variable from some other module?  Or, are you trying to get the `socket` that belongs to the same browser that is making the current http request?

Comment: I think I need both of them because I want to add the current socket to a channel and then I need to emit a message to all sockets in this channel